# View position in DBGrid when scrolling in Delphi

Tags: delphi, scroll, dbgrid

I have a DBGrid on a form.  The DBGrid has many columns, so an horizontal scroller is displayed.  I scroll the DBGrid view to the right to see more columns.  If I select a row, the DBGrid view is automatically reset to view the first column (As if I scroll back to the left most position).

Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you have *goRowSelect* in the grid options.  This forces the selected col to be the first non-fixed column, so whenever the row changes the code to scroll the selected cell into view forces the first non-fixed column to be visible.

Since *goRowSelect* also effectively disables the horizontal scrolling with the keyboard I try to live without it.  You can use custom drawing of the grid cells to show all cells of the current row with the proper colours for selected cells, even though only one cell is really selected.  I use this also to show different colours depending on whether the grid is focused or not, similar to what a standard tree control does.  For this to work properly you do however need to handle not only grid cell navigation events, but some other events too, like *OnEnter* and *OnExit* of the grid, *OnActivate* and *OnDeactivate* of the Application, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to ask for the scrollbar position

```
GetScrollInfo(Self.Handle, SB_VERT, SIOld);
```

and use `SetScrollInfo( )` to put it back. There's probably a better way. `SelectedField` is another way (get/set it as needed).