# Problem with horizontal scrolling on TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid

I have problem with wide grids of type TStringGrid. If user scrolls grid to the right and selects row then
grid automatically scrolls left so first column can be seen, but not the column user is interested in. How to prevent such scrolling?

I use TurboDelphi (Delphi 2006).

My grid has standard options with changes:

- goColSizing=True
- goRowSelect=True

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335526/view-position-in-dbgrid-when-scrolling-in-delphi/336404#336404) to a similar question for the data-bound grid.